# Unexpected design choice in Python's ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, config, built-in

I tried to read from and write to a config file like so:

```
with open(file, 'r') as ini:
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read(ini)
        config['section'] = {'foo':45}
with open(file, 'w') as ini:
        config.write(ini)
```

I just couldn't get it to read the already saved data. It took me quite a while to find out that I actually have to read from the file like this:

```
config.read(file)
```

Why is it not consistent? Why do I have to read and write in two different ways? Is there a good reason for this kind of design choice, something about I/O that I don't know yet?

And why did it not raise an exception when I tried to read from a file buffer?

Are there other built-ins that are inconsistent in file handling?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read), and the documentation for the alternative `readfp` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs there are actually two (sort of three if you count the `list` argument) ways to do it:

```
import ConfigParser, os

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('defaults.cfg'))
config.read(['site.cfg', os.path.expanduser('~/.myapp.cfg')])
```

The `filename` version also allows you to pass multiple filenames in and the `ConfigParser` will automatically handle (ignore) the files that are missing.  This is common idiom for config files where you might have a default config file and then a locally defined one.

Why it is inconsistent that it is called `readfp` but `write` and not `writefp`...?  You could read up on its [history](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParser).  Also [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout).

In the end, designs (and designers) aren't always perfect, idiosyncrasies aren't always caught, but once it becomes a standard lib, the interface is frozen.

We can look at the `ConfigParser` source to see why `read()` with a *fileobject* is silently ignored:

```
def read(self, filenames):
    """Read and parse a filename or a list of filenames.

    Files that cannot be opened are silently ignored; this is
    designed so that you can specify a list of potential
    configuration file locations (e.g. current directory, user's
    home directory, systemwide directory), and all existing
    configuration files in the list will be read.  A single
    filename may also be given.

    Return list of successfully read files.
    """
    if isinstance(filenames, basestring):
        filenames = [filenames]
    read_ok = []
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            fp = open(filename)
        except IOError:
            continue
        self._read(fp, filename)
        fp.close()
        read_ok.append(filename)
    return read_ok
```

Oh -- wow -- this is going to be interesting!

Your *fileobject* isn't a `basestring`, so it assumes it must be iterable. It then iterates on the *fileobject*.  Which means it reads your file for a list of filenames it tries to open.

For example, I made a file `f` and filled it with a-g, each letter per line.  `strace` shows:

```
open("f", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
open("a\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("b\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("c\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("d\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("e\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("f\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("g\n", O_RDONLY)                   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

...and since the API is designed to ignore files it can't open, it just ignores the errors.

From the docs,

> If none of the named files exist, the ConfigParser instance will contain an empty dataset. An application which requires initial values to be loaded from a file should load the required file or files using readfp() before calling read() for any optional files:

This behavior is surprising enough that I've filed http://bugs.python.org/issue27351 to ensure they are aware of this edge case.

Comment: I will accept the answer if you can also explain why the method doesn't raise an exception when trying to config.read from a file object instread of a string. It just failed silently.